# how to use a column value in a select statement itself in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

let's say i hae a table schema named person
it has these columns listed below

```
id  |  name  | age  | gender | activities_in_order | created_date
```

the value for activities_in_order column is a boolean...true or false..

how to use this column as reference in a select statement itself ?

here's my pseudo code

```
SELECT * FROM Person   ( if activities_in_order = true ORDER by field_here else if activities_in_order = false Order By field_here )
```

Comment: This doesn't really make sense. The `ORDER BY` is applied to **all** rows from the result. The value of the column might change for every row. Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select * from "Person"
order by
  case when activities_in_order then field_here else field_there end;
```

Maybe your data design can be improved though.

Comment: This is right.  The only problem will be if `field_here` and `field_there` are different datatypes.